# Can I override a method for a View when using XML layout?

Tags: android, overriding

I have a ListView in a XML layout but I want to override one of the methods. Is this possible?

```
    this.setContentView(R.layout.my_view);
    ListView lv = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.lstIngrSelect);
```

Now say I want to override a method of lv. How can I do that, if possible?

Comment: which method you want to override? More details will be helpful.

Comment: sorry. I want to override the OnFilterComplete method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a subclass of ListView ("MyListView") and override the OnFilterComplete method there.  Then, in your layout xml, (fully) reference your class -- com.my.company.MyListView -- instead of ListView.  Use your class name in the code as well:

```
MyListView lv = (MyListView) this.findViewById(R.id.lstIngrSelect);
```

The resulting object should act identically to a regular listview except for your custom code.

Comment: Sorry for my stupidity but how do I reference my new class in the xml layout?

Comment: instead of <ListView... /> use <com.my.company.MyListView... />.  Obviously the full reference is based on whatever company, package and class name you have set up for your project.  All of the other attributes can be identical.